# Class method that alters the object

Tags: python

I've been learning about classes in python and I was trying to write a reverse method for an extended string class, which looks like:

```
class NewString(str):
    
    def reverse(self):
        self = self[::-1]

string = NewString('Python')
string.reverse()
print(string)
```

I expected it to print 'nohtyP' but it doesn't. It keeps the original value of the string and prints 'Python'. Can anyone explain to me why this doesn't work and how I could change the class to get it to do what I expected. There is no purpose for this other than learning more about how classes work.

Comment: You are not replacing the object, you are replacing the reference to the object.

Comment: Keep in mind that strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Class don't accept parameters in its self rather from a constructor. Construct your class first so you can pass value of your parameters to the class variable

Comment: 1. To do this you will have to subclass from a mutable type string (like byterray maybe), or override all functions.
2. Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` is just a local variable in the method.  Reassigning it won't mutate the object it referred to before. Since strings are immutable, so are objects of your string subclass. All you can do is return new string objects from the methods:

```
class NewString(str):
    def reverse(self):
        return self.__class__(self[::-1])  # casts to the specific type of self

string = NewString('Python')
rev = string.reverse()
print(rev)
# nohtyP
type(rev)
# NewString
```